# jquery opens page in Div but does not relay 'id' GET value

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

```
print '<td><a href="JobsFiles/Update_Jobs_Table.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onclick=" Update_Jobs_DB()"><img src="media/edit.png" width="15" height="15" title="EDIT"></a></td>';
```

This above is php for a html table cell with href and id from mysql.

```
<!-- load Update_Jobs_Table.php page into right div -->
<script>
function Update_Jobs_DB() {
  $("#div_rightMenu").load("./JobsFiles/Update_Jobs_Table.php"); 
  return false;
}
</script>
```

This above jquery loads page into Div fine.. but am unable to work out how to relay the id with the page to the div... GET[id] is always empty.
Any hints appreciated.

Found a solution that works!!

```
print '<td><a id="JobsFiles/Update_Jobs_Table.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" href="#" onclick="javascript:getID(this)"><img src="media/edit.png" width="15" height="15" title="EDIT"></a></td>';
```

This uses 'this' id but this id contains the url and the id from a mysql database.The js below loads this link into a div with the variable for retrieval of the Get id from mysql.. thanks all for your help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getID(theLink){

    $("#div_rightMenu").load(theLink.id);
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try this `./JobsFiles/Update_Jobs_Table.php?id=<?php echo $Uid; ?>`

Comment: where do you define the var `$Uid`? Can you show us the code

Comment: Sorry that $Uid was me trying different ways.. Should have been  <script>
function Update_Jobs_DB() {
  $("#div_rightMenu").load("./JobsFiles/Update_Jobs_Table.php"); 
  return false;
}
</script>

Comment: edited original script

Comment: you are loading the page without `$id` when click event happens. you should try something like `$(this).attr("href");` instead of hadrcoding url in `Update_Jobs_DB` function

Comment: Thanks Undefined_variable. Will do some research on what u said.